# How to measure the voltage of a battery under load to roughly estimate remaining charge?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, voltage-measurement, lead-acid

I am designing a system where I'll need to use a micro controller to measure the voltage of a 12V lead acid battery to determine it's state of charge. I was planning to simply use a voltage divider and call it a day but as I read on about it it became to appear slightly more sophisticated than I anticipated.

As I'm learning, when under load, the battery's voltage can drop by quite a bit. If the measurement happens at a time of full load the voltage will probably be 10V or less, and that would freak my system out. Is there any way I can go around this problem without having to implement solutions that include monitoring when the battery is under load?

Comment: Can you measure the load current? Or better yet, cut the power consumption?

Comment: @Ralph well I'll have a current sensor, yes, and I can cut the load but that would be inconvenient, I would very much like to avoid doing that unless it's absolutely impossible otherwise.

Comment: The only really accurate way I know to estimate a battery's state of charge is a coulomb counter.  That, in turn, relies on knowing the battery's capacity, and I don't know how well tracking battery capacity works with lead-acid cells (it works pretty good with LiPo).

Comment: Do you know how to switch to a standby ultracap while measuring no load voltage?

Comment: This is one of those questions that appears here very often because the search terms are not intuitive.  Research Lead-Acid Battery State-of-Charge (SOC) and have a peek at the [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com).

Comment: @php_nub_qq Just to throw a kink in things, *back-in-the-day* we didn't have fancy MCUs and used hydrometers. The acid density varies significantly over the range of charged to discharged. I can imagine constructing a sensor design that could be read by an MCU that would be quite useful. Or just buying one. Have a look at the [oscillating U-tube method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillating_U-tube), for example. But this is only one of at least three ideas I've in mind. Just another thing to toss out there to add to the confusion.